# How can I show variable numbers of items in the nested RecyclerView of another RecyclerView?

Tags: adapter, android-recyclerview

So, think categories with differing numbers of items in each. Right now I'm using two RecyclerViews, one nested inside the other, each with its own adapter. The first displays each instance of the category (e.g. days) and an instance of the second adapter. The second adapter displays items that ideally want to fall under the first category (e.g minutes, seconds).

The issue is that since each time a list item is created and passed, the first RecyclerView populates with the aggregated items from the second. This makes sense because the second is still adding each time the list updates.

How can I control the second RecyclerView's number of displayed items? Ideally, I want them to be malleable, i.e. each "Day" item in the first can have as many or as few "minute" entries in the second. The adapter codes are below. Thanks!

First Adapter:

>

```
     public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_rows, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;

>     public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RemindersAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.recyclerTwo.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        holder.month.setText(reminderList.get(position).getMonth());
        subAdapter = new SubAdapter(reminderList, mContext);
        holder.recyclerTwo.setAdapter(subAdapter);
    }
```

Second Adapter:

```
>     public SubAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_rows, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder; }

>     @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SubAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.hour.setText(reminderList.get(position).getHour());
        holder.content.setText(reminderList.get(position).getContent());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return a different number from `getItemCount()` in your second adapter.  There's nothing special about the nested case that should break this.

It looks like your problem may be that you're passing the same list into every SubAdapter:

```
subAdapter = new SubAdapter(reminderList, mContext);
```

You probably meant to be passing only the sub-items in.